# How to keep asp.net mvc web application alive to continously running

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-timeout

I created an asp.net mvc project. In this project I want some code always running. I publish my code on a web hosting service. For first time I start the application by sending an http request to my domain and I expect the application to be always kept alive and never shut down. But this does not happen.

Even I saw some solutions that say if I ping my domain sometimes in my code prevent the application from shutting down. But this solution extend application life cycle to about 24 hours (not always!!!)

Here is my code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                // some codes
            }catch(Exception exp)
            {
                // log the exception message, (but any exception hasn't occurred till now
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax: (by using this code, the application shutdown shortly, in this way I use a dummy controller)

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    static Thread keepAliveThread = new Thread(KeepAlive);

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        keepAliveThread.Start();
        Main.main();
    }

    protected void Application_End()
    {
        keepAliveThread.Abort();
    }

    static void KeepAlive()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://mydomain/Home/Index");
            req.GetResponse();

            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax: (by using this code, application stay running about 24 hours. in this way I don't use any controller)

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        Main.main();
        Timer timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(refreshSession));
        timer.Change(0, 5 * 60 * 1000); // 5 min

    }

    static void refreshSession(object state)
    {
        Unirest.get("http://mydomain/");
    }
}
```

Is there any better solution for my purpose? If yes please give me a sample code.

Comment: If you have access to iis configuration, you can change the application pool start mode to always running.

Comment: no, I haven't access to it, I mention that I publish my application on a hosting service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally that's called scheduled/background jobs. You can use "scheduled" for googling. Most hosting  provide some means to do it form the control panel. On azure for example you could use "webjobs".

Note that there are some well-known solutions for background jobs, like [hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) for example. Don't re-invent the wheel unless you really have to.

Comment: fire-and-forget functionality is the solution for my purpose? isn't it?

Comment: it depends on why do you want to keep the app alive. The point is, that background service, controlled by the hosting environment, may be more reliable than any ping.

Comment: this solution neither works, application stops after about 8 hours